# Multiple exception catch block java 8 eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8, unhandled-exception

I'm getting an unhandled message exception for IOException. As you can see in the pasted code I've handled the IOException. The JDK for both eclipse & the project is Java 8 update 121 so I *know* catching multiple exceptions is supported. What am I doing wrong?

```
    try (InputStream inputStream = BatchMessageProperties.class.getClassLoader().
            getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName)) {

        load(inputStream);
        //need to make sure all properties are present & not null.
        validate(this);

    } catch (IOException | InvalidBatchMessagePropertiesFileException ex) {

        logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
```

Comment: I guess the call to getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName) is the source of the Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do rethrow `ex` inside your catch block, which may be an `IOException`, right?

Comment: oh... i get it. my method actually propagates up the InvalidBatchMessageProperties exception but not the IOException. 

Thanks.